# how to express adverbials by using preposition"with"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

how can we express "she was going home and at the same time she was crying"
she was going home with crying or she was going home by crying.
could you please help me?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it must be in the progressive tense? Did you reject the following solutions: (1) As/While she walked home, she cried // (2) She cried all the way home

Comment: It is possible to use the progressive aspect, but not with *with*: "She was crying as she went home." You have to use *as.*

Comment: She was going home with tears flowing down her cheeks.

Comment: She went home crying.